# Gulp throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in minimal setup

Tags: npm, gulp

I was following the [getting started guide of Gulp on GitHub](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) step by step when I got this error when running `gulp` [at this point](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#test-it-out):
`C:\dev\web\gulp_test\gulpfile.js:1`
`(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ��v`
`.                                                             ^`
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`
`.    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)`
`.    at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)`
`.    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)`
`.    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)`
`.    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)`
`.    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)`
`.    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)`
`.    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)`
`.    at execute (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^3.7.0\index.js:26:18)`
`.    at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js:173:63)`

What's the problem?

 The gulpfile.js content is the same as the one in the guide

 Here some platform specs

- NPM version (`npm -v`): 3.10.3
- Node version (`node -v`): v6.3.0
- Node Process (`node -p process.versions`): v6.3.0
- Node Platform (`node -p process.platform`): win32
- Node architecture (`node -p process.arch`): x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's failing for no particular reason. Starting a new project fixes the problem.